Importing an Excel file multiple times in Tableau Public does not update data tables
I am new to Tableau and I'm trying out importing from Excel files.
This seems fairly simple, but when I import and Publish a simple Excel file and then add a row and re-add the data source, the updated values do not apply. Is this normal? Am I doing something wrong?

Tableau caches connected data once a connection is made, it does not automatically update when there is a change to the connected datasource.
If you are just trying to update your workbook with the new data, you will need to refresh your datasource/ extracts.
If you are not seeing the changed data on your published workbook (online workbook in Tableau Public), you need to re-publish your datasource.

Did you republish the datasource after modifying it ?
What you're describing is not normal, but a step or two could be missing to make it like how you want it.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
